# Como obtener una imagen desde una vista vbhtml

Tags: vb.net, .net, mvc

Estimados , como puedo obtener una imagen desde una vista vbhtml en este formato :

```
@Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.FchNacimientoPER)                
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.FchNacimientoPER, new With {.class="form-control"})
```

Deseo obtener la imagen como un arreglo de `bytes` , la puedo obtener como un `byte()` desde la vista? o debo mandarla al controlador y allí pasarla a un `byte()` para trabajarla .

Comment: la imagen a dónde está? en la base de datos, un archivo en el disco o donde?

Comment: la imagen esta en el disco duro , deseo hacer un upload de esa imagen en la vista y pasarla al controlador

Comment: Ahi publique una respuesta. Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Podrá con algo así:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Archivos",
                 FormMethod.Post, new { id = "attachment", enctype = "multipart/form-data", encoding = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 

    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" />

   <input type="submit" value="Guardar"/>

}
```

En el controlador:

```
<HttpPost> _
Public Function Add(uploadFile As HttpPostedFileBase) As ActionResult
If uploadFile IsNot Nothing AndAlso uploadFile.ContentLength > 0 Then

    Dim tempFile As Byte() = New Byte(uploadFile.ContentLength - 1) {}
    uploadFile.InputStream.Read(tempFile, 0, uploadFile.ContentLength)

    User1.file.Content = tempFile

    User1.file.Save()
End If

Return RedirectToAction("Index")
```

End Function

donde `User1.file.Content` es de tipo `byte[]`